# ListBox Map J and K Keys to Up/Down Arrow Keys

Tags: wpf

I have a ListBox and I simply want to bind the J and K keys to whatever commands the up and down arrow keys are bound to. The up and down arrow keys in a WPF listbox typically change the selected item to the previous/next item. I thought something like this should work:

```
  <ListBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="J" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" />
    <KeyBinding Key="K" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" />
  </ListBox.InputBindings>
```

I'm probably being too simplistic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `DependencyClass` on the commands. Define the commands in `ListBox.InputBindings`:

`XAML`

```
<ListBox Name="SampleListBox" Width="200" Height="200" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" SelectedIndex="{Binding MySelectedIndex}">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding NextCommand}" Gesture="CTRL+J" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding PrevCommand}" Gesture="CTRL+K" />
    </ListBox.InputBindings>

    <ListBoxItem>Sample 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Sample 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Sample 3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Sample 4</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set your data
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

        // Set focus
        SampleListBox.Focus();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class with commands
/// </summary>
public class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public ICommand NextCommand 
    {
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public ICommand PrevCommand
    { 
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int MySelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(MySelectedIndexProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(MySelectedIndexProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MySelectedIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MySelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MySelectedIndex = 0;

        NextCommand = new SimpleCommand(SetNext);
        PrevCommand = new SimpleCommand(SetPrev);
    }

    private void SetNext()
    {
        MySelectedIndex += 1;
    }

    private void SetPrev()
    {
        if (MySelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            MySelectedIndex -= 1;
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;

    public SimpleCommand(Action p_action)
    {
        _action = p_action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_action != null)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}
```

In the class contains two `ICommand's`: `NextCommand` and `PrevCommand`. Also there is a DependencyProperty `MySelectedIndex`, which contains the current index of the item. In `SimpleCommand` always return `true`.

This is just an example that still need to check the total number of `Items ListBox`. Or instead of increasing the `SelectedIndex`, use `ScrollViewer` logic.

`Extension`

Example with `ScrollViewer`:

To scroll through the items in the `ListBox`, you must first have access to it. Below is the corresponding function:

```
public static DependencyObject GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject Object)
{
    if (Object is ScrollViewer)
    {
        return Object;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(Object); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Object, i);
        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);

        if (result == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Simple function scrolling:

```
private void OnScrollDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyListBox.Items.Count > 0) 
    {
        // Get ScrollViewer from ListBox
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(MyListBox) as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
           // Increment offset - scrolling Down, sub - scrolling Up
           scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + ScrollListBoxOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for effort. The ListBox already has the scrolling/selection behavior I want only it's wired to the up/down arrow keys. I would have thought there would have been a way to get at this behavior and wire it to the J/K keys. Having to implement the behavior myself just to pick different keys seems a bit lame (not you, WPF). Between this and the idiotic focus issues, I'm about ready to give up on WPF.